# Solicit-response send port and pipelines in BizTalk

Tags: biztalk

My question is regarding the send and receive pipelines in a single solicit-response send port. Is it possible the receive pipeline (response part) can access information from the send pipeline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of the box no, as per [Access promoted property in the response message context on Request-Response port](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4bdf5b57-abcf-485d-b609-88d1f58ca2c4/access-promoted-property-in-the-response-message-context-on-requestresponse-port?forum=biztalkgeneral)

So you have the following options

1. Orchestration.   You can retain the value of the request here and add it to any response going back to whichever calling system.
2. Have the system that is sending the response to BizTalk include that value in a field, then you can just promote that.
3. Custom Pipeline Components that use some sort of static dictionary to store any values from the Request, then populate the Response.

Comment: We finally went with #2